# Storyboard instantiated Master View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I have instantiated a view controller (`UINavigationController`) from storyboard, for whom I declared the size as `Master`. However, whenever I instantiate the controller in *code*, it returns a full view controller. How can I instantiate as a 'Master View Controller'.

**Explanation:**
I declared a Master View Controller in my storyboard, and gave it a storyboard identifier. The size of this controllers view is {320, 1024}. When I instantiate the same controller in my code, (`[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"filterView"]`) it returns a view controller with size {768, 1024}. But I want a view controller of the size of the master.

Comment: Please explain a little bit more.

Comment: Which type of devicd do you use to simulate, iPad or iPhone

Comment: @Danyun: I'm working on iPad.